# Python error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

On my Fedora 25 I have configured the virtual environment with python 3.5
and after upgrading the system to Fedora 27 I cannot longer launch django app withing the virtual env (python manage.py runserver) neither check the version of the python:

error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Could you please advice what to do next? I'm not advanced user in terms of python configuration. Shall I reinstall python 3.5 or try to set up virtual environment once again?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: you probably need to reinstall the virtualenv

Comment: Recreate the virtualenv and reinstall Python packages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you phd and Kevin L.!

The virtualenv -p python3 my_env_name solved the issue.

Then it was important to restore dependencies via pip module

Anyone doing the migration (to newer linux or another pc)  I also recommend to dump the dependencies with  pip freeze > requirements.txt.

Comment: Please take into account that `pip freeze` must be run while the virtual env is still alive. Once it's not working you cannot run python scripts including `pip`.